# Форма регистрации пропускает одинаковые ip

Tags: база-данных, ip, форма, регистрация

Как сделать так что бы БД при регистрации новых пользователей не пропускала одинаковые ip? В моем коде БД пускает, не записывает дату регистрации, но на сайте в кабинете  отображается дата рег. 01.01.1970. Вот код

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['send'])) {
    $log=$_POST['login'];
    $mail=$_POST['email'];
    if(!systemPM('/^[a-zа-я0-9_]{4,12}$/iu', $_POST['login'])) {
        $err[]='Неверного формата логин!';
    }
    else
    {
        if(sql_n("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login`='$log' ")>0) {
            $err[]='Извините, но пользователь с таким логином уже зарегестрирован в системе.';
        }
    }
    if(!systemPM('/^[a-zа-я0-9_-]{6,25}$/iu', $_POST['pass'])) {
        $err[]='Неверного формата пароль!';
    }
    if($_POST['pass']!=$_POST['pass2']) {
        $err[]='Пароли не совпадают!';
    }

    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $err[]='Неверного формата E-mail!';
    }


    else
    {
        if(sql_n("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$mail' ")>0) {
            $err[]='Извините, но пользователь с таким E-mail уже зарегестрирован в системе.';
        }
    }
    if(count($err)>0) {
        echo '<div class="err"><div class="errtext">'.$err[0].'</div></div>';
    }
    else
    {
    if(sql_n("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `regip`='$ip' ")>0) {
        $err[]='Извините, но с вашего IP уже проводилась регистрация.';
        if($err) {
                        sql_q("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `regip`='$ip' ");
                    }



}
    else
    {
        $regdate=time();
        $referal=0;
        $referal2=0;
        $goin='';
        if(isset($_COOKIE['ref_id'])) {
            $id=$_COOKIE['ref_id'];
            systemES($id);
            sql_q("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login`='$id' ");
            if(sql_n()>0) {
                $referal=sql_r();
                sql_q("UPDATE `users` SET `nrefs`=`nrefs`+1 WHERE `login`='$id' ");

                // получаем реферера 2 ур.
                sql_q("SELECT `ref_id` FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$referal' ");
                if(sql_n()>0) {
                    $referal2=sql_r();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(!empty($_COOKIE['location'])) {
            if(systemPM("/^(http:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9-])+(\.([a-zA-Z0-9-])+)*(\.([a-zA-Z0-9~\/])+)+)?$/", 'http://'.$_COOKIE['location'])) {
                $goin=$_COOKIE['location'];
            }
        }
```

Comment: А где в коде происходит запись регистрации? И да, по IP фильтровать плохая идея. У пользователей в большинстве случаев динамические IP и с неизвестным интервалом времени используемый, например ваш на данный момент IP, может быть выдан вашему соседу ... и т. д.

Comment: Да ладно бы только динамические IP. Некоторые провайдеры используют NAT, и на всех клиентов получается один общий внешний IP-адрес. То есть из клиентов такого провайдера зарегистрироваться сможет только один.

Comment: вот продолжение  if(!empty($_COOKIE['location'])) {
   if(systemPM("/^(http:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9-])+(\.([a-zA-Z0-9-])+)*(\.([a-zA-Z0-9~\/])+)+)?$/", 'http://'.$_COOKIE['location'])) {
    $goin=$_COOKIE['location'];
   }
  }
  $password=md5('FDLja842$5'.md5('xsf*7%%812'.$_POST['pass'].'*&%$').'fsd(8^^4');
  $reg=sql_q("INSERT INTO `users`(`login`,`password`,`email`,`regdate`,`insert_sum`,`away`,`ref_id`,`ref2_id`,`goin`,`regip`,`ip`,`updated_last`) VALUES('$log','$password','$mail','$regdate','1','$regdate','$referal','$referal2','$goin','$ip','$ip','$regdate') ");
  if($reg) {

Comment: @Dn3pr1k, добавьте этот комментарий в текст вопроса, отсюда вряд ли кто-то будет читать, потому что не удобно. Для правки вопроса нажмите кнопку "править" под текстом вопроса.